# Using Weights In Multilabel Matrix Instead Of Numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling, multilabel-classification

Suppose we have a [multiclassification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) problem.
The data matrix stores integers representing the labels.

Would it be correct to build a matrix like that with the data as `float()` or some kind of probability like below:

```
[[0.71561032442075889, 0.27956959249497948], ...]
```

Instead of binary labels like these:

```
[[0, 1], ...]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, the problem would no longer be a multiclassification problem, but a regression problem. Simply due to fact that your labels are no longer short-scoped integers, but continuous.

Comment: @E.Z. thanks for your answer, if you could put your comment as answer i will upvote as accepted answer. but please explain a bit more why it will be a regression task rather multiclassification

Comment: @E.Z. for the berief advice you gave me. actually my transformed input data is already probability. it is the output of LDA model, for example a document has some topics with some probabilities. I am going to make the labling like give the probability to each tpic or keep the same probability in the label matrix. please let me know if you have any idea on this approach :)

Comment: It is much better then to fit a regressor, not a classifier. That would work better. In what cases would you keep the same probability taken from the label matrix?

Comment: @E.Z. I am writing another question related to this I will put link here. please help me also with the concept there:) thanks

Comment: @E.Z. may I ask you please to have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654463/concept-behind-the-transformed-data-of-lda-model  many thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) is a task to divide a given set (inputs) into **N** amount of classes based on their common properties and core features. If you only have two classes (**N == 2**), then the problem would be a binary classificaiton. As a general rule, such classes are presented as integers starting from zero:

```
X = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
y = [1, 0, 1]  # two classes => binary classification task
```

If you have more than two classes (**N > 2**), then this would be a multiclassification task. Note that we do not consider any transformation techniques:

```
X = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6]]
y = [1, 0, 1, 2]  # three classes => multiclassifaction task
```

---

Apart from classifying input data, there is also a task to build regressions. The main difference between a classification analysis and a [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is that we strive to establish a solid mathematical relationship between inputs and targets. One of the main questions we may pose ourselves during a regression analysis is what happens to our target variable when a certain input is varied. In that case, target vector is presented on a continuous scale, i. e. it may consist of absolutely any digit, positive or negative:

```
X = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 1]]
y = [12.5, -36.8, 12.5, 22.32]  # regression problem
```

---

#### Brief advice

If you wish to rebuild your `y` to be able to solve multiclassification problem, you should first of all have a valid and rational technique to transform your binary targets into continuous ones like you have shown in the question. If you believe your approach follows a common sense, then you may round the values of `y` vector to decimals and thus establish eleven classes: `[0.0, 0.1, ..., 0.9, 1]`. Of course, next step would be to fit a classifier with the transformed data.

I hope that helps.