# Concept Behind The Transformed Data Of LDA Model

Tags: evaluation, text-classification, lda, topic-modeling, multilabel-classification

My question is related to *Latent Dirichlet Allocation*. Suppose we apply LDA on our dataset, then apply fit transform on that.

the output is a matrix that is a collection of five documents. Each document consists of three topics. othe output is below:

```
[[ 0.0922935   0.09218227  0.81552423]
 [ 0.81396651  0.09409428  0.09193921]
 [ 0.05265482  0.05240119  0.89494398]
 [ 0.05278187  0.89455775  0.05266038]
 [ 0.85209554  0.07338382  0.07452064]]
```

So, this is the matrix that will be sent to a classification method for an evaluation purpose.

For the classification part, we need the labels for each row. But we do not have the labels which means I have to create them by my own.

---

One approach could be getting the highest probability for each topic as the corresponding label.

For example, the labels may be like so:

```
[2,0,2,1,0,]
```

However, this is very simple example.

I can also consider two highest probability for each document if each documents only has two topics. So, the example would be like this:

```
[[ 0.0922935   0  0.81552423]
 [ 0.81396651  0.09409428  0]
 [ 0.05265482  0  0.89494398]
 [ 0.05278187  0.89455775  0]
 [ 0.85209554  0  0.07452064]]
```

As you can see I have the rule of keeping the same probability for each label if they have the highest probabilities.

Which approach is correct? Has anyone used any other approach that is more meaningful?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If there are no labels provided for your data, then this problem is called clustering. You may read more about it __[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)__. It is still possible to cluster the topics, even if you do not have targets.

Comment: @E.Z. Actually LDA is kind of clustering for the topics, but I want to evaluate the output using a classification method

Comment: I am not sure if your labeling approach would work, you should implement and verify it with some metrics. By the way, you have the raw data, so you may label documents according to the information they possess, though, it is cumbersome.